# Python Pandas Key Error When Trying to Access Index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data set of stocks along the columns, dates down the rows(downloaded using Bloomberg's Python API - please ignore fact that they are all 'NaN' - this is just for this portion of the data):

[image]

I am trying to extract the Month and Years from the Index in order to later do a pivot:

```
values['month'] = values['date'].apply(lambda x: x.month)
```

Where values is the name of the above DataFrame.

However this gives an error: 'KeyError 'date'

Running:

```
values.index
```

Looks fine:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-01', '2010-01-02', '2010-01-03', '2010-01-23',
           '2010-01-24', '2010-01-29', '2010-01-30', '2010-01-31',
           '2010-02-13', '2010-02-14',
           ...
           '2017-08-12', '2017-08-27', '2017-08-31', '2017-09-01',
           '2017-09-03', '2017-09-09', '2017-09-24', '2017-09-29',
           '2017-09-30', '2017-10-01'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=593, freq=None)
```

So I am just wondering what is going wrong and why I don't seem able to access the actual index here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First columns is called `index` and `date` is `index.name`.

You can check it by:

```
print (df.index.name)
```

So you need [`DatetimeIndex.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month.html) and [`DatetimeIndex.year`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.year.html):

```
values.index.month
```

EDIT:

For custom string format dates are used as [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
values['name'] = values.index.strftime('%B - %Y')
```

Comment: In the final code snippet for values.index - doesn't it show that the index name='date' - or have I misunderstood something here?

Comment: It is `print (df.index.name)`

Comment: Btw, what is desired output after pivoting? Because I see MultiIndex in columns.

Comment: But the index is not accessible via df['date']?

Comment: No, because `df['date']` is for select column `date` only.

Comment: Thanks. The desired output would be to show, for each stock, the Month, Year value in each cell. So for example, each day of November 2016 would be 'pivoted' to just show a single row Nov - 2016

Comment: Only is possible if `MultiIndex` in index, then `df.index.get_level_values('date')`, `df.index.get_level_values('another name of level')`

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: You write that "First columns is called `index`", but if I try calling `df['index']` it fails, while if I provided any other column's name, it would have returned values for that column. So, how can I use the same syntax for the Index? What do I provide it `df[???]` to get values of the index. Thank you

Comment: @Confounded - `df.index ` ;)